# Get sprints associated to a given board using JIRA Python library results in error

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm trying to get the list of sprints associated to a given board (as described in [JIRA Python module documentation examples](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#examples)):

```
sprints = gh.sprints(board_id)
```

where `board_id` is the ID of the board to be retrieved (1175 for reference), previously retrieved as with `jira.boards()`.

I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\exceptions.py", line 49, in raise_on_error
    raise JIRAError(r.status_code, error, r.url)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: HTTP 404: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>404</status-code><message>null for uri: https://jirafoo.bar.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/1175?includeHistoricSprints=true&amp;includeFutureSprints=true</message></status>"
https://jirafoo.bar.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/1175?includeHistoricSprints=true&includeFutureSprints=true
```

(I'm using jirafoo.bar.com to ofuscate the actual hostname of the JIRA server)

Any clues about what can be the cause, please? Thanks!

**EDIT:** reference information about JIRA server version, just in case it helps:

> Agile project management for Kanban and Scrum software development
>   powered by Atlassian GreenHopper (v6.1.6). Bug tracking and project
>   tracking for software development powered by Atlassian JIRA
>   (v5.1.1#772-sha1:c73db67)

**EDIT:** I have found that using this URL directly (e.g. in my browser) I'm getting a JSON with the list of the sprints:

```
https://jirafoo.bar.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprints/1175
```

Maybe the JIRA module is not using the right URL for the `sprints()` method (I understand that this would be a bug in the JIRA python library)? Or maybe I'm using the wrong method on the `gh` object? My Python JIRA module version is 0.32 (I think the most recent one at time of writting this).

Comment: I have opened an issue in source code repository related with this at https://bitbucket.org/bspeakmon/jira-python/issue/138/error-in-greenhopper-class-sprints-method

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and could not find the answer anywhere.

Your question made me realize that the URL was the problem.
It called "/sprintquery/" while the URL you posted is "/sprints/"

I finally implemented the fix myself on my computer.
I've backup the file :

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py
```

and modified the following line:

```
r_json = self._get_json('sprintquery/%s?includeHistoricSprints=true&includeFutureSprints=true' % id,
                                base=self.AGILE_BASE_URL)
```

for this one:

```
r_json = self._get_json('sprints/%s?includeHistoricSprints=true&includeFutureSprints=true' % id,
                                base=self.AGILE_BASE_URL)
```